# Почему "вылитый"?

Tags: этимология

Поиском не нашла такого вопроса тут, поэтому хочу спросить: почему, говоря о большом сходстве, мы говорит "вылитый"? Куда вылитый и откуда?))
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бронзовые и др. скульптуры из металла создаются следующим образом: делается форма, в которую заливается металл, после чего форма разбирается - скульптура готова. Естественно, таким образом можно получить почти бесконечное количество идентичных литых фигурок, поэтому про что-то очень похожее тоже стали говорить "вылитый", будто бы сделали по одному лекалу.